# Permanently modify the /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: linux

Every time I reboot my Ubuntu 22.04, I don't have internet access. I have noticed that the /etc/resolver.conf gets to these default settings:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

Once, I modify the nameserver to point to my **Router IP address**, the traffic is immediately restored.

How can I permanently fix this?

Comment: That way all it does it points to the systemd resolver. You need to either configure systemd resolver or disable it completely.

Comment: *How can I permanently fix this?*   By googling bro https://www.tecmint.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-debian/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways in which you can make permanent DNS changes on resolv.conf in Linux.

Use Resolvconf framework
Set the name server IP address on your Interface settings
Update the DNS server settings on dhclient.conf

https://kifarunix.com/make-permanent-dns-changes-on-resolv-conf-in-linux/#resolvconf